# Insert a character after match with bash

Tags: linux, bash, regex, shell-script, sed

I'm writing a bash script. I need to introduce a colon after the first occurrence of a character.
`/c/Users/ertwr/org/readme.html` and in order to open them with the native Windows browser the need a colon after the unit letter `/c:/Users/ertwr/org/readme.html`

I use the following expression which works remarkably well, even for multiple files or whitespaces, but only for the specified unit since I can't store the unit letter in the regular expression.

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/env bash 
IFS=$'\n'
${HOME}/scoop/shims/chrome "${@/\/\c\//\c\:\/}"
```

### The problem is it **only** works for the  `C` letter the way it's written. So I need a way to make it work independently for **ANY** letter.

### Things I've tried and don't work for multiple files or files with spaces:

#### - can't capture the regex

I really want this one to work, but I'm doing something wrong.

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'

regex=(\/[a-zA-Z]\/)
if [[ "$@" =~ "$regex" ]]; then
    ${HOME}/scoop/shims/chrome "${@/$BASH_REMATCH/${BASH_REMATCH}\:}"
fi
```

#### - sed append

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/env bash 
IFS=$'\n'
WADDR=`sed 's|\<[a-zA-Z]\>|&:|' "$@"`
${HOME}/scoop/shims/chrome "${WADDR}"
```

Sed particularly feeds the content of the file as url, instead of the name of the file. While it works when using a text file as input.

Comment: For Windows programs you can just use normal Windows style path. For example, here notepad.exe opens a file `/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe "C:\path\to\file"`. Don't forget to mention the double quote.

Answer (score 4):

To convert WSL style path to Windows style, use `-w` option with `wslpath` binary. *By default* the mounted path in WSL is `/mnt` so I choose it in example. You can remove the `/mnt` part from the path.

For example,

- Command: `wslpath -w "/mnt/c/Windows/System32"`
- Output: `C:\Windows\System32`

For more valid options just execute `wslpath` and it will show the help page:

```
wslpath: Invalid argument
Usage:
    -a    force result to absolute path format
    -u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
    -w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
    -m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with '/' instead of '\'

EX: wslpath 'c:\users'
```

Here is an *example of simple shell script* to open a text file in Notepad:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

read -p "Enter WSL style path: " variable
echo "Opening file in Notepad.exe"
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Notepad.exe $(wslpath -w "$variable")
```

Here is the modified shell script from question:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
echo "${@}"
WADDR="$(/bin/wslpath -w "${@}")"
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Notepad.exe "${WADDR}"
```

### Further details:

- [Automatically Configuring WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/)
- [What’s new for the Command Line in Windows 10 version 1803](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/)

Answer (score 0):

who knew? I solved it on my own.

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'

if [[ "$@" =~ \/([a-zA-Z])\/ ]]; then 
    ${HOME}/scoop/shims/chrome "${@/$BASH_REMATCH/\/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\:\/}"
fi
```

So, to make it compatible with an NT URI, to feed it to a binary, I just need to remove one of the matched `/` like this.

```bsh
#!/usr/sbin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'

if [[ "$@" =~ \/([a-zA-Z])\/ ]]; then 
    ${HOME}/scoop/shims/chrome.exe "${@/$BASH_REMATCH/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\:\/}"
fi
```

And without self-up vote and white kinght upvotes. Just code.